# Creating a new user and trying to get the user_id for session id but getting first id PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to fix my sign up in PHP, when I create a new user my user id instantly becomes the first one available, if I have 100 users and I create a new one the user id should be 101 which it is on the database but on my session it becomes 1, if I delete the first user and the only user available has the id of 2 it becomes 2. What is wrong in my code? Cant seem to debug it.

```
<?php 

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email =  $_POST['email'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];


    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "smarttime");
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO users (use_name, use_email, use_pass) values ('$username', '$email', '$pass')");

    $test = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from users");

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($test); 


    if(empty($username) || empty($pass) || empty($email) || empty($pass2))
    {
        header("Location:signup.php");
    }else{
        if($row['use_email'] == $email){
                    header("Location:login.php");
        }else{
                $query;
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['use_id'];
                $_SESSION['nome'] = $row['use_name'];
                header('Location:logged.php');
                exit();

        }
    }

 ?>
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">





  <head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>SmartTime</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css\main.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>



  <body>  

      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" >SmartTime</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <span class="navbar-text">
    <a href="/login.php" >Login</a>&emsp;
    <a href="/signup.php" >Sign Up</a>
    </span>
  </div>
</nav>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="card card-container">
            <!-- <img class="profile-img-card" src="//lh3.googleusercontent.com/-6V8xOA6M7BA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/rzlHcD0KYwo/photo.jpg?sz=120" alt="" /> -->
            <img id="profile-img" class="profile-img-card" src="images/Doge.png" />
            <p id="profile-name" class="profile-name-card"></p>
            <form action="validatesignup.php" method="post" class="form-signin">
                <span id="reauth-email" class="reauth-email"></span>
                <input type="text" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
                <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email address" required>
                <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" name="pass" placeholder="Password" required>
                <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" name="pass2" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-signin" type="submit">Login</button>
            </form><!-- /form -->
            <a href="login.php" class="forgot-password">
                Already have an account? Sign in!
            </a>
        </div><!-- /card-container -->
    </div><!-- /container -->

    </body>
  </html>
```

new code

```
<?php 

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email =  $_POST['email'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];


    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "smarttime");

    // Insufficient input
    if(empty($username) || empty($pass) || empty($email) || empty($pass2)) {
        header("Location:signup.php?msg=please+fill+all");
    } else {
        $stmt_email_test = mysqli_prepare($con, 'SELECT use_email FROM users WHERE use_email=?');
        $stmt_email_test->bind_param('s',$email); // 's' for one string
        $stmt_email_test->execute();
        $stmt_email_test->bind_result($email_test);

        if($email_test != null) { // Email exists
            header("Location:login.php");
        } else if( $pass != $pass2 ) { // Check if password repetition is ok
            header("Location:signup.php?msg=passwords+do+not+match");
        } else { // Everything is fine, do insert and fill session
            $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO users (use_name, use_email, use_pass) values (?,?,?)");
            var_dump($stmt->error);
            $stmt->bind_param('sss', $username, $email, $pass); // 'sss' for 3 strings
            $stmt->execute();


            // Get the new user_id
            $new_user_id = mysql_insert_id();

            // Fill Session
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $new_user_id;
            $_SESSION['name'] = $username;
            header('Location:logged.php');
            exit();

        }
    }

 ?>
```

Comment: `var_dump($stmt->error);` has to be `var_dump($con->error);`

Comment: tring(52) "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"

Comment: `$stmt_email_test->close();` after `$stmt_email_test->bind_result($email_test);`

Comment: now I got `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_insert_id() in C:\xampp\htdocs\validatesignup.php:34 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\validatesignup.php on line 34`

Comment: has to be mysql***i***

Comment: I put mysqli which made it work but it redirects me to log in because it didnt set the session..

Comment: `<?php

session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
   header("Location:login.php");
} 
?>`

Comment: this is my code to get into logged.php

Comment: yes `session_start()` is missing

Comment: now my user isn't created on the database

Comment: redirects me to login.php without creating the user on db

Comment: which means the email already exists. make var_dump on $email_test

Comment: but it doesnt exist and how do I see the var dump if it redirects me into login.php

Comment: sorry you need a $stmt_email_test->fetch() after bind_result

Comment: yes, but how do i see the result if it redirects me to login.php?

Comment: `mysqli_stmt Object ( [affected_rows] => -1 [insert_id] => 0 [num_rows] => 0 [param_count] => 1 [field_count] => 1 [errno] => 0 [error] => [error_list] => Array ( ) [sqlstate] => 00000 [id] => 1 )`

Comment: it creates them but keeps redirecting me to login.php even though i already did a session_start(); is there a way to check the value of id?

Comment: `Warning: mysqli_insert_id() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\validatesignup.php on line 36`

Comment: had to put $con inside the id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a prepared-statement version.
You should use prepared statements to prevent sql-injections have a look at [mysqli_prepare](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.prepare.php)

Furthermore, I highly recommend to **NOT** store the password as plain text. Php offers a easy and safe way to store passwords: [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/de/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/de/function.password-verify.php) is all you will need :)

```
<?php

// Insufficient input
if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['pass']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['pass2'])) {
    header("Location:signup.php?msg=please+fill+all");
    exit;
}

$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "smarttime");

$stmt_email_test = $con->prepare('SELECT email FROM users WHERE email=?');
$stmt_email_test->bind_param('s', $email); // 's' for one string
$stmt_email_test->execute();
$stmt_email_test->bind_result($email_test);
$stmt_email_test->close();

if ($email_test !== null) { // Email exists
    header("Location:login.php");
    exit();
}
if ($pass !== $pass2) { // Check if password repetition is ok
    header("Location:signup.php?msg=passwords+do+not+match");
    exit();
}

// Everything is fine, do insert and fill session
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO users (name, email, pass) values (?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $username, $email, $pass); // 'sss' for 3 strings
$stmt->execute();

// Get the new user_id
$new_user_id = $stmt->insert_id;
$stmt->close();

// Fill Session
session_start();
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $new_user_id;
$_SESSION['name'] = $username;
header('Location:logged.php');
exit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `mysqli_insert_id` to get last id and use in select query, like this :-

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO users (use_name, use_email, use_pass) values 
('$username', '$email', '$pass')");
$id = mysqli_insert_id($con);

$res = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from users WHERE user_id={$id}");
if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
 $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
}
```

Comment: also this will interfere with my check to see if the email is already in use

Comment: @JohnDoesCode It may not work out of the box, however the way you're doing it in your question you're just assigning the first user that can be retrieved from the database -- that's why `id` becomes `2` after you've deleted the user with `id=1`. The code provided in this answer shows you how to retrieve the `id` of the user that you've just created, so that you can assign it to `$_SESSION['user_id']`, which makes a lot more sense than just grabbing the first user that can be found.

Comment: how do i do that

Comment: still doesn't create the session like that, user_id = null

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this code in you first else condition-

```
$sql = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE email = '".$email."' ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // store the user_id of the person newly registered to $_SESSION['user_id]
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $_SESSION['user_id] = $row["user_id"];
    }
    header('Location:dashboard.php');
} else {
    echo "No user found!";
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: It creates the user but the session doesn't get an user_id I know this because to see the next page you need a user id on the session and it refirects to the login page

Comment: you have to redirect the user to the dashboard after setting up the session variable. You can do it within the if condition, outside the while loop.

Answer (score -1):

$test = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from users");

In this line you have to pass the email or email & password to get the corresponding id

$test = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from users where use_email = ".$email);

It will work for you .. just add where condition to that query to retrieve particular user details.